# How to make a navigation sticky when it reached to another top nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two navigation one is on the top and another is in content. I try to make the second sub menu as sticky when it reached to the top menu not the very top offset of browser. But i failed to make it sticky when it scrolled to top. Also how can I add class on on menu item when active 'href' scrolling.

[JSfiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/rupomkhondaker/bum44vtk/)

**JS Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $filter = $('.denpen-menu');
    var $filterSpacer = $('<div />', {
        "class": "filter-drop-spacer",
        "height": $filter.outerHeight()
    });

    if ($filter.size())
    {
        $(window).scroll(function ()
        {
            if (!$filter.hasClass('navbar-fixed') && $(window).scrollTop() > $filter.offset().top)
            {
                $filter.before($filterSpacer);
                $filter.addClass("navbar-fixed");
            }
            else if ($filter.hasClass('navbar-fixed')  && $(window).scrollTop() < $filterSpacer.offset().top)
            {
                $filter.removeClass("navbar-fixed");
                $filterSpacer.remove();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: You want the "secondary nav" to become sticky when the "main nav" scrolls down to it. And when you scroll back up when the secondary nav comes to it's previous position it should stop being sticky? Correct?

Comment: Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/bum44vtk/2/) what you had in mind?

Comment: Yes its correct ! You can put the code in answer .  is there any way to add a class on active anchor item when scroll

Comment: Yes, the logic would be similar. I'll explain my logic in the answer, so you try doing that part yourself ok?

Comment: Yes please :) Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we should fetch the starting position of our `subNav`and store it as **"startingPoint"**

> var **startingPoint** = $('.stuckMenu').offset().top - 48;

*Notice the `- 48` part, that's about the height of our main navigation, and a bit less just so it feels better when they touch.*

The key part of the logic is this part here:

```
if (!subNav.hasClass('navbar-fixed') && $(window).scrollTop() > startingPoint)
{     
    $filter.addClass("navbar-fixed");
}
else if(subNav.hasClass('navbar-fixed') && $(window).scrollTop() < startingPoint)
{      
    $filter.removeClass("navbar-fixed");
}
```

Where we ask:

1. Is our *subNav* sticky yet? Is the top of the window touching it currently?

   > Ok its not sticky yet but the window touched it, make it sticky - fixed.
2. Ok so our *subNav* is sticky, is the top of the window above the original position of our *subNav*?

   > It is above? Ok I do not want it to be sticky any more, so we'll just remove the class.

## [Check out the example here](https://jsfiddle.net/bum44vtk/5/)

Comment: There, I hope i explained it well enough. Sorry i took so much time... If there is something I missed please tell me and I'll be happy to explain.

Comment: Yes I understand your logic well. Thanks

Comment: Can you help me how I can add a `class="active"` on each menu item when the anchor of the menu reached  or clicked. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gUWdJ/3/)

Comment: Actually I posted a question some time ago, related to that [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39756240/custom-scroll-spy-optimization). There is an example there, its working correctly. So maybe you could use it, or even better improve it. :)

Comment: but not using bootstrap